# How to add page names in uppercase in nuxt without using router.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

[image: Example]

I am not able to make the page name as Index.vue but for other pages I did and it works.

Any idea how to resolve this one?

PS: For this project, I am preferring PascalCase for pages. I don't want to configure router.js manually.

Comment: Have you got any errors/warnings?

Comment: I didn't get any errors in console but when I tried loading the http://localhost:3000 it doesn't take the Index.vue template instead I'm getting 404 error.

Comment: do you really need it? i mean `index.vue` is the route `/`?

Comment: @Ifaruki yes, indeed

Comment: I don't really see what you get from using PascalNaming your pages files.. Only in components (name, not files) is recommended

Answer (score 1):

Since Nuxt.js automatically creates the vue-router based on your /pages structure, if you really need to have a /Index route, you could create a folder called "Index", and then include your index.vue template there.

Then you're able to call the /Index route from nuxt-link:

```
<nuxt-link to="/Index">Click Me</nuxt-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

first create a directory with name you want after create index.vue file in this directory

Comment: Sounds like good idea but it won't work for the homepage right?
E.g. If we add a folder then the URL will be localhost:3000/Index

Comment: no if you create a folder with a name you want and in folder create index.vue file ، your route change to folder name
for example you created a folder with name 'test' and in this folder created index.vue file .
Eventually you have this route :localhost:3000/test

Answer (score 0):

I think like this question you can make nuxt case-sensitive in routing

[How to make routes case sensitive in Nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57489947/how-to-make-routes-case-sensitive-in-nuxt)

By adding this code:

```
// nuxt.config.js
router: {
  extendRoutes(routes) {
    for (const key in routes) {
      routes[key].caseSensitive = true
    }
  }
}
```