# How do I force Nuxt to generate lowercase routes?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

When I `yarn generate` a (static) Nuxt project, it will create folders for each of the routes. I have many routes with "Various CASING", and many of them will generate lowercase folder names (in addition to the cased ones), but NOT all of them, and I'm trying to understand why.

The app works fine when loaded from the root (/), because the routes are all loaded async. However, when I link directly to a route that has NOT been lower-cased, I get a 404.

I can't seem to find any pattern for why some routes get duplicated and others don't. So I'm hoping there is a way to force all routes to generate a lowercase alias to fully support direct linking.

(fwiw, direct linking using the proper Casing works fine for those routes that don't generate lowercase aliases)

Comment: Take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57489947/how-to-make-routes-case-sensitive-in-nuxt

Comment: thank you for the link .. i tried experimenting with `extendRoutes`, but nothing changed within the generated static folder